# Why can't we add different variables in linear equations together?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Even though this seems to be an absurd question I would like to know why we can't add different variables together?What keeps us from not adding unlike variables together?

For example if we have an system of linear equation as:

1. $1x_1 + 2x_2 = 3$
2. $2x_1 + 4x_2 = 6$

we are obligated to add $1x_1$ and $2x_1$ together instead of $1x_1$ and $4x_2$.

Could anyone tell the reason of adding two same variables together instead of different variables.

Comment: No idea what you are asking.  Can you try to clarify?

Comment: There is no reason you can't add $1x_1$ and $4x_2$, but the problem is that you don't know what that will equal.

Comment: Well, if you really want to add them, you get $1x_1+4x_2=-2x_2-2x_1-3$ (using substitution), but that's not really useful, is it? We add $1x_2$ and $2x_2$, because the system gives us that it equals 3. Same for $2x_1$ and $4x_2$. We are not given (directly) what it means it we add $1x_1$ and 4x_1$, so there is no point in adding those.

Comment: @ShaVuklia:Do you mean to say we can't visualize of adding two equations on a graph?

Comment: @justin Adding two equation would mean that you add everything on the left side together and everything on the right side together. So you would get: $3x_1+6x_2=9$, but that's not really going to help you further. If you add the two equations, you simply get a new equation, and you can graph it, if you want. I would suggest you try to let go of the visualisation as a means of understanding the system - at least for now - and focus on the algebraic properties instead. (That's way easier)

Comment: Of course you can add $1x_1$ and $4x_2$. If you do, you get $x_1+4x_2$, just like if you add one apple and four pears, you get a collection of fruits consisting of one apple and four pears. I don't really understand what the question is.

Comment: Short answer:  You can add 2x and 3x because x and x are the *same* number.  2(7) + 3(7) = 5* 7.  2(539)+ 3(539).=5(539) and you can generalize 2xsomething + 3xsomething = 5xsomething You can't add 2x + 3y because x and y are different numbers and you have no idea how they are related.  2(7) + 3(59) is one thing and 2(57) + 3(17) is another and there is no way to say 2xsomething + 3xsomething_else = some definite pattern.

Answer (score 4):

When you add the two equations, you get a sum of four terms on the left. It's common to  simplify by combining the coefficients with similar variables, but by no means necessary. You're welcome to write $(1x_1+2x_2)+(2x_1+4x_2)$ and leave it like that. Or write $(1x_1+4x_2)+(2x_2+2x_1)$. It's common to write $(1x_1+2x_1)+(2x_2+4x_2)$ because then we can easily observe that this is equal to $3x_1+6x_2$, but writing the sum in that form is a **simplification of the four-term sum**. All four of those sums are equal. So, in some sense you're asking the wrong question - you mean to ask about simplifying sums.

So let's ask the right question: why do we simplify like that? Because $x_1$ and $x_2$ are different types of things. Imagine that $x_1$ are rocks and $x_2$ are flowers. If you have $1$ rock and $2$ flowers on Monday and $2$ rocks and $4$ flowers on Tuesday and someone asks you how many total rocks and flowers you had between the two days and you said $1+4=5$ rocks and $2+2=4$ flowers, you're wrong because you're failing to correctly identify objects as rocks vs flowers. Likewise, you have a certain amount of $x_1$ and a certain amount of $x_2$ and you're failing to draw this distinction.

One common objection to this explanation is that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are numbers, and therefore the same kind of thing. That's half right, but misleadingly so. $1$ kilometer and $1$ mile are both units of distance, but that's not the right sense of the phrase "kind of thing." If we redo the above example about distances walked, the exact same objection applies to the rocks and flowers case.

Comment: :I have thought about this answer while posting this question.Could you tell graphically why we can't add unlike variables.More clearly what happens if add these variables together?

Comment: @justin you can add $2x_1$ to $3x_2$. You get $2x_1+3x_2$, which happens to not be the same thing as $5x_1$. Does that part make sense to you?

Comment: @justin also, I have heavily edited and expanded my answer so check to make sure you read the most recent version

Comment: :That's true cause no one add an rock and a flower as you told.Could you tell what happens when we add two same variables graphically together?

Comment: @justin I don't know what that means. Do you mean "draw a picture"? What kind of picture. "Adding things graphically" doesn't refer to anything in particular.

Comment: @justin My interpretation of that question is that you want me to rewrite the example about rocks and flowers but draw pictures of rocks and flowers. You're welcome to draw that picture yourself (learning is a dynamic process!) but I don't have the ability to make such an image on my phone and I'm a little confused as to what additional information such an image would impart. **Perhaps it would be useful if you asked a question, or pointed at why you don't find this answer compelling**

Comment: :What might we get on a graph when we add the equations in the question together using $x_1$ and $x_2$ as the axis

Comment: @justin that question indicates a very fundamental misunderstanding of the concepts involved. Why don't you ask me a question about a part of my answer that you don't understand, don't agree with, or think needs elaboration?

Comment: :Could you tell what graph would we get if we plot this equation : $(1x_1+4x_2)+(2x_2+2x_1) = 9$ as such without simplifying it

Comment: @justin Simplying the equation doesn't change its graph. Here's a graph: http://www.meta-calculator.com/online/?panel-102-graph&data-bounds-xMin=-10&data-bounds-xMax=10&data-bounds-yMin=-7.28&data-bounds-yMax=7.28&data-equations-0=%22(1*x%2B4*y)%2B(2*x%2B2*y)%20%3D%209%22&data-domains-0=%5B-10%2C10%5D&data-rand=undefined&data-hideGrid=false

Comment: You can isolate one variable (say $x_1$) on the left side, and the other stuff on the right. Then simplify everthing and you get: $x_1=3-2x_2$. You can plot this in the same way you plot $y=3-2x$ (just replace $y=x_1$ and $x=x_2$).

Comment: For justin:  rocks and flowers might be a nonintuitive and abstract example.  But if you had x number of 12 packs of oranges and y number of 5 packs of oranges you have 12x + 5y oranges.  You can't simply combine the 12 packs with the 5 packs to get 17 packs because the number of each could be utterly arbitrary and independant.  But if you know you have x 12 packs and the *same* variable x of 5 packs, then because they *are* the same, you can combine, one by one, each 5 and each 12 pack, to get 17x oranges.

Answer (score 2):

When we say $2x_1$ the $x_1$ could be anything.  It could be $7$.  It could be $5,924,791.57$. Or anything else. So $2x_1$ could be anything.  It could be $14$.  It could be $11849583.14$.  But its value will depend on whatever $x_1 $ is.  If you know what $x_1$ is you know what $2x_1$ is.

And when we say $3x_2$ then $x_2$ could be anything.  It could be $2$ and it could be $-4,723,206.14$. Or anything else. So $3x_2$ could be anything.  It could be $6$ and it could be $-14169618.42$.  But its value will depend on whatever $x_2$ is. If you know what $x_2$ is you know what $3x_2$ is

$2x_1 + 3x_2$ could be anything.  It could be $20$ if $x_1 = 7$ and $x_2= 2$.  It could be $-14169604.42$ if $x_1 =7$ and $x_2 = -4,723,206.14$.  Or could be anything else.  What it equals will depend on two different variables.  If $x_1=7$ then $2x_1 + 3x_2$ could be wildly different values depending on what $x_2$ is.  If what know what $x_1$ is you do *NOT* know what $2x_1 + 3x_2$ is because $x_2$ could vary wildly.  If you know what $x_2$ is you do not know what $2x_1 + 3x_2$ is because $x_1$ could vary wildly.

We can not express $2x_1 + 3x_2$ in terms of a single variable because it is not dependent on only one variable. It's dependent on *two* variables each of which could have values completely independently of the other.

So the real question isn't why cant we add $2x_1 + 3x_2 = 5x_{somethingelse}$ but why *CAN* we add $2x_1 + 5x_1$ to get $7x_1$?

Well, because both $2x_1$ and $5x_1$ are dependent upon the *same* variable.  If we know what $x_1$ is we have to know what *both* $2x_1$ is and $5x_1$ is.  And if we know what both $2x_1$ and $5x_1$ is then we know what they both add up to.

We can *never* know what $2x_1 + 3x_2$ add up to if we only know *one* of the variables so we can't express a sum of *both* the variables in terms of just one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "since the axises $x_1$ and $x_2$ are orthogonal". So adding $x_1$ and $x_2$ would be like taking a couple of steps in the vertical and then in the horizontal direction but still you can't :

*Add a step in the vertical direction by taking a step in the horizontal direction or vice-versa*